# How does information move on a topology bus network?

Tags: topology

For exemple in AS-Interface there is the master who send information and then the slave send a response but in topology bus all systems are connected to one wire so the information will go to all slaves, how the slave know its for him ?

could transceivers do this task?

Comment: This really too broad a question.  Can you give a more concrete example?

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert on bus topology, but I'll do my best to answer this:

All frames/packets in the bus network will have a source and destination address. All systems in the bus sniff every frame and ignore the ones that aren't destined towards them. Most of this work can be done by a decent NIC.

Where my system is connected to a bus, I will see:

Message 1: Destination: John, source: Sheila (I'll ignore this)
Message 2: Destination: Sheila, source: John (I'll ignore this)
Message 3: Destination: Me, source: John (I'll read this and respond if necessary)

Etc.